# Django form not submitting on post

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have django form that is not submitting upon clicking Submit. I try to click on the button to submit the information nothing happens. No errors or messages of any kind show up in terminal or in developer in Chrome. There is no JS on this page just straight html: I used the same approach on the a different project but for this it doesn't work. What could be the issue with my code.

```
models.py
class Department(models.Model):
    depart_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    depart_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.depart_name
```

```
views.py
class DepartmentAddView(CreateView):
    model = Department
    form_class = DeptAddForm
    template_name = 'hrms/department_form.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

```
forms.py
class DeptAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    depart_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'span8',
            }
        ),
        label = "*Department Name",
    )
    departt_code = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'span8',
            }
        ),
        label = "*Department Code",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['depart_code', 'depart_name']
```

```
hrms/department_form.html
<form class="form-horizontal row-fluid" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Department Code</label>
       <div class="controls">
           {{ form.depart_code }}
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Department Name</label>
       <div class="controls">
          {{ form.depart_name }}
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
       <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-success">Submit Form</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your `forms.py` where you are overriding the fields , for field `depart_code`,you have written `departt_code` instead of `depart_code` ,that's whats causing the issue. So, your correct `forms.py` should look like this :

```
class DeptAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    depart_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'span8',
            }
        ),
        label = "*Department Name",
    )
    depart_code = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'span8',
            }
        ),
        label = "*Department Code",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['depart_code', 'depart_name']
```

Comment: Facing the issue in this code,, but has not typo
```

Comment: @BryanMark what issue? I tried running your code ,worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

## check your views.py file again

this section specially,

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return redirect('/')    # is this right url ?? (read below)
```

this redirect here will decide on which web page you will be redirect after the submission of your form so make sure this ('/') path is mentioned in your urls.py file and if not then change this path with right path (something which exists in your urls.py file)

Comment: `(/)` points to the homepage with
`path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),` `return redirect` comes after `form.save()` method. In my understanding the form data will be saved and throw a redirect error if it doesn't return a valid view

Comment: if your homepage path is this path(' ', views.dashboard, name='dashboard') and you want to redirect your yourself on homepage after submission then leave it empty in views.py also means, return redirect(' ').

Comment: That is not wrong, it will redirect to base url of site that is '127.0.0.1:8000'